# Sound implementation in Symbian^3

Tags: symbian, implementation, nokia, audio

I am looking around to implement sound in my Symbian^3 game application. Are the examples of Symbian S60 work well for Symbian^3 devices? I am in doubt because syntax is different for S60 and Symbian^3.

If anybody can provide me any link where I could find any method to implement sound in Symbian^3 application. Looking for early reply.

Thanks in advance.

Atul Prakash Singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at CMdaAudioPlayerUtility 
[link](http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_3rd_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/html/SDL_93/doc_source/guide/Multimedia-subsystem-guide/MMFClientApi/AudioPlay.guide.html) . Although the link is to a 3rd ed doc , the Class remains mostly the same.